# PHP/MongoDB Error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException'

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

So i'm using MongoLab as my DB Host and recently I have been running into this issue.  Whenever I load up my application for the first time with a cleared cache on the first run, I receive this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message
>   'couldn't send query: Connection reset by peer'

After I refresh the page again and the application loads without any issues.  I was wondering if anyone knew the reason for this error or had any fixes to resolve this.

Thanks and Happy Holidays.

Comment: Which version of the Mongo Server are you running?

Comment: Hey whobutsb can you post some code? Might be irrelevant but could help people figure out whats going on.

Comment: What's your network configuration like? Normally that error indicates a timeout over ssh.

Comment: Try with the `persist` option and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you hosting your app code?

What is likely happening is that the first connection is taking a while (longer than the set timeout) to connect to the MongoLab host. The connection is then established so that the second request uses it.